# Override Joomla Front page layout

Tags: php, content-management-system, joomla1.5, joomla-extensions, frontpage

i am using joomla 1.5 and using a front page blog layout for my front page as of now,

Now i want to switch from that layout to something more vibrant, intuitive to user.

i am looking for something like a unstructured home page like a common wall where i can place new updates here and there, something pinned kind of thing on a board.  a Pinterest type kind of layout,

I dont want these static and boring articles need something dynamic and more user interactive.

i there is any module to do that, or is this possible.??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try such module like K2. Demo: http://demo.getk2.org/

Another way - download Theme for Joomla.
For example like this: [JSN Groove Template](http://demo.joomlashine.com/joomla-templates/jsn_gruve/index.php).
And notice, that most of themes can install their own modulex and plugins for proper work, so dont forget to make back-up ;)

Also a lot of modules for content and layot change u can find at [Joomla Content Extensions](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/authoring-a-content/content-construction)

Comment: But it will Require to Change My existing Template., i was trying to continu with my existing template and changing only the front page. in ref to JSN groove template

Comment: Of course u must change template. But this components provide many tweaks in admin panel without writing code. Try to look in that way.